# No instance of function template "tan(_Ty _Left) noexcept" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense, c++20

I'm trying to make an exercise given in the "Beginner C++20 From Novice To Professional" book and the request is this:

> For your birthday you’ve been given a long tape measure and an instrument that measures angles (the angle between the horizontal and a line to the top of a tree, for instance).
> If you know the distance, d, you are from a tree, and the height, h, of your eye when peering
> into your angle-measuring device, you can calculate the height of the tree with the formula
> h + d*tan(angle). Create a program to read h in inches, d in feet and inches, and angle in
> degrees from the keyboard, and output the height of the tree in feet

I arrived to the point where I had to write the following lines:

```cpp
const auto height{ heightToEyes + feetFromTree * std::tan(angle)};
const unsigned int inches{ static_cast<unsigned int>(std::round(inchesPerFeet * (height - feet))) };
```

It gives me an error for both std::tan and std::round but the compiling process goes just fine.

[image]
[image]

I'm using C++20 and I have the following properties enabled in the project:

/std:c++latest

/experimental:module

/internalPartition

[image]
[image]

I would like to know why it does this?
Is this just a problem with MSVC++ IntelliSense which is not done yet for "/std:c++latest"?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal snippet? Did the problem exist in the latest VS2022? tan and round work fine for me.

Comment: Since the question is related to intellisense, consider adding IntelliSense tag.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT The code works just fine for me too, but it gives this error which is annoying.
It could maybe be related to VS2022 intellisense which is not well made yet for the latest C++ standard but I honestly don't know.

Comment: By the way, I didn't get the  intellisense errors.